# Syndrome decoding

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I have a conceptional question to the concept of "syndrome decoding" (i.e. the procedure to decode a received vector).

Let's say I'm given a generator matrix G and a received vector v = (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0). How can I decode the received vector?

Here is what I would do, but I'm not sure:

1. Bring G to standard form (I | A)
2. Parity check matrix is: $H = (-A^t | I)$
3. Compute $v \cdot H^t$, the received code is the one which has been encoded.

Is this correct?

Thanks for any correction!

Comment: $v \cdot H^t$ is _not_ the "one which has been encoded", it is the _syndrome_ of the _error pattern_ from which one needs to determine what the error pattern was. Many different error patterns will ;produce the same syndrome and the decoder's job is to determine which is the most likely one (hint: fewer errors are more likely than many errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its incomplete.
Take the received word $v$ and compute the syndrome $s = Hv^t$.

Here you need to do some preliminary work.
Write $v=c+e$ for codeword $c$ and error vector $e$. Then $Hv^t = Hc^t+ He^t = He^t$. Thus the syndrome $s$ tells you the error vector $e$. Then $c=v-e$ gives the decoded codeword. To do so, you need to make a list of pairs $(s, e)$ where $s$ is a syndrome and $e$ is a vector (coset leader) with $s=He^t$ of minimal Hamming weight. Note that there are cases where $e$ is not uniquely determined by $s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found here some examples, too: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/mcs425-s08/handouts/syndrome_decoding.pdf

Comment: What I don't get: How are the coset leader(s) determined?

Comment: I think it requires enumeration.